# Dynamically Print Months of the Years in PHP

Tags: php

I want to dynamically print next 16 months with the year from now in the following pattern.

> 2018 : JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC
>
> 2019 : JAN, FEB, MAR, APR

Comment: Good. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

One way is with `for` loop up to 16 times

```
$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));      // Get this month
$result = [];                                                // Result array
for ($i = 1; $i <= 16; ++$i) {                               // Loop from 1 - 16
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month));  // Get year
    $month = date('M', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month)); // Get month
    $result[$year][] = $month;                               // Push to result year=>value
}

foreach ($result as $key => $value) { // Loop thru each year
    echo $key . ': ' . implode(', ', $value) . '<br>'; // Echo each month
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer unattempted questions.  Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: See what Jiri has said under the question?  This is not just something cute that volunteers write on bad questions.  This is a minimum requirement for pleas of support.  When you help people who do not try, you are not helping them - you are making them weaker developers and dragging down the quality of SO content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <?php

     for ($i=1; $i<=16; $i++) {
         $month = date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$i, 1, date('Y')));
         echo $month. '<br>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Posting it as an answer due to less reputation.
try it

```
<?php

for ($num_of_month = 1; $num_of_month < 16; ++$num_of_month) {


   echo $arr_months[] = date("F", strtotime("+$num_of_month months"));


}
```

Comment: Posting solutions as answers is the correct action (after the OP has searched, researched, and attempted to self-solve).  Never post solutions as comments.  Always add explanations with your code to add value to your post.